# Set an specific command for a python program

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I would like to develop a command-line program that located in `C:\assistant\myassis.py`
Everytime when i want to run my program I should enter this command in my command line: `$ python3.6 C:\assistant\myassis.py`
I want to set an specific command for my program which let me to use my program in every folder with a short command.
for instance:
`$ assis download file --test` should require `$ python3.6 C:\assistant\myassis.py download file --test`.
How can i do it in my windows10?

Comment: create `.bat` file with launcher and add location of this file to PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To run python programs simply clicking on it or entering its name you can set association. Python installer makes it by default, don't know why you havn't one. To check it enter `assoc .py` then `ftype <type which assoc shows>`, to set - `assoc .py=Python.File` then `ftype Python.File="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*`.
2. To run a script/program from any folder without entering full path one has two options:

   - PATH environment variable - put your script anywhere in PATH, for example - C:\WINDOWS, C:\PythonXX\Scripts, C:\Sys. Check path - `path`, set path - `path %PATH;My dir`, set/check permanent path - Win+Break -> Additional system parameters -> Environment variables.
   - apppath: Edit registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` add entry like other.
3. If you don't want to enter '.py' suffix, and run you `script.py` simply as `script`, add ';.PY' to PATHEXT variable.
4. Looking at your examples which begins with '$' it seems you are using not Windows shell and/or python but some port of bash, maybe windows subsystems for linux (WSL) or git bash. In this case, paragraph 1 changes to 'add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as the first line of you scripts', p.2. - use separate, Linux PATH variable, p.3. - use alias

Comment: For part 1, please do not use `assoc` and `ftype`. They only work on the classic per-machine settings in "HKLM\Software\Classes". The computed file association is based on several keys nowadays, with an overriding "user choice" maintained by the desktop environment shell (Explorer). Use the shell's "open with" dialog. Select the Python icon with a rocket (payload launcher) on it and choose to always open .py files. Do not choose to browse for "python.exe" in this dialog. That will create a broken file association instead of using Python's installed ProgId.

Comment: For part 4, we should always add the shebang to the script and preferably without "env" (e.g. "#!/usr/bin/python3"). The py.exe launcher parses virtual Unix shebangs to determine which registered interpreter to run and also handles Windows paths, commonly for virtual environments (e.g. "#!C:\assistant\Scripts\python.exe"). Using "env" makes it search `PATH` instead of using the registry, and by default there's no "python3.exe" in Windows Python installations.

Comment: Apparently Git bash, if that's what the OP is using, is not distributed with Python 3. (It has Perl; now I feel slighted.) But "#/usr/bin/python3" should be fine in MSYS2 and WSL, which at least allow installing Python 3.